# How can I make the hover effect on a particular division as used in the land rover website?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried to change the cursor on hover, but it changes in only one direction. I want to make same as it is in [landrover](http://www.landrover.in/index.html) website

Comment: You have provided almost no details. Can we see your code, and where you think you may have an issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using just CSS;

```
       elementInQuestion {cursor: crosshair; }
```

When the elementInQuestion is moused over, the cursor changes. When you move the mouse to another element, the cursor goes back.

Comment: This guy downvoted me out of tantrum, so upvote for him because he's correct but not overly helpful to the OP with his CSS mastery. PS, css isn't "code" ;)

Comment: @ChrisW. How is this NOT helpful? It explains EXACTLY what must be done.

Comment: @ChrisW. What guy? You are the one who commented that the post was not helpful, which it is. The post is tagged with CSS3 and I provided the exact syntax to use. PS - CSS is code, it's just not programming code, it's a declarative code.

Comment: Sorry amigo I get annoyed when people down vote something for no genuine reason, but that's what makes us different people, if I had seen the same mistake on yours it would have been a friendly comment pointing it out. The OP has 1 point in years of SO use, it's not like either of us would get any points, I help people here to help people, I forgot the hover thing in there because I was tinkering with something myself and didn't really review anything before I hit ctrl P, it happens. No worries man, have a good weekend....oh but css isn't code, sass I could buy but css no.

Comment: @ChrisW. Well, amigo, your answer worked, but showed incorrect & extraneous code to get there. You're right that the OP has more limited knowledge than you, so showing more code than is necessary is not a great idea.  You are just being overly sensitive about a valid down vote. And, whether CSS is code or not really is not opinion for you, personally, to "buy", it's actually a fact that it is. You should investigate what terms like declarative, functions, procedural and markup mean. (Hint: all are forms of code.) You have a nice weekend too!

Comment: You win man, time to move on and help the next one's :)